# Fetch CSV file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have csv file that contains data which I want to use in my Rails app. Rows look like this:

```
#⇓⇓   ⇓⇓    ⇓⇓                ⇓⇓  ⇓⇓                     ⇓⇓    
1ttAAAttAnaattFrench PolynesiattPFttAustralia and Oceaniatt-17.352606tt-145.509956
2ttAAEttAnnabattAlgeriattDZttAfricatt36.822225tt7.809167
3ttAAFttApalachicolattUnited StatesttUSttNorth Americatt29.7276066tt-85.0274416
```

Is there a gem or Ruby library that can fetch this kind of csv? (note `tt` separation.)

Comment: Also, check out SmarterCSV which has better CSV processing than Ruby's standard CSV module.

Comment: @AnthonyE when recommending a gem/library, please add a link to it: https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain old good Ruby stdlib’s [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) will do. In [options](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new), one should specify:

```
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", col_sep: "tt") do |row|
  # use row here...
end
```

Another option would be to just read a file line by line and do:

```
line.split(/tt/) #⇒ array
```

Comment: Hey, can you add the link to the smarter_csv gem into answer aswell and maybe a little info where it is the best to call this to save data into database?

Comment: I won’t add a link to SmarterCSV since it is absolutely irrelevant here. I answered the question as it was stated. Whether you are in doubt on “how to store the data into a database,” ask a different question. This site has it’s rules.

Comment: Ok I apologize. I tought it would be nice  to bundle all this stuff into one place so people have info about various options and some extra related info. I'll accept answer as soon as system let's me.

Answer (score 1):

check out SmarterCSV - it creates Ruby hashes for each CSV row, and you can rename the columns. This way you can use the hash directly to create or update a Rails model. e.g.:

```
  filename = 'yourfile'
  options = {
    :col_sep => 'tt', :chunk_size => 10,
    :user_provided_headers => %w[attr1 attr2 attr3 attr4 attr5 attr6 attr7]   # use the attribute names for your model
  }
  SmarterCSV.process(filename, options).each do |array|
    array.each do |hash|
      YourModel.update_attributes(hash)
    end
  end
```

Please check out https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv for all the available options.